# Reload UiPageViewController in seconds

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, uipageviewcontroller

I am using UIPageViewController in my iOS application. I fetched data from my web api on page initial load. After that I want to update values with new information of UIPageViewController in every 10 seconds. I tried to update it like that but it is still not updating.

```
pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool)
```

Kindly help.

Comment: This is just a `delegate` method, share your code that you tried so far.

Comment: Ok. Basically I just want to reload UIPageViewController because in every few seconds datasource is updated and I want to update it with new data. Any thing can we use here like in table view we reload data with tableview.reloadData()

Answer (score 0):

You can forcefully reload data by making dataSource to nil and then again adding to self. In this case it will again call all the datasource methods from beginning.

```
func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {
        if !completed { return }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            pageViewController.dataSource = nil
            pageViewController.dataSource = self
        }
}
```

Hope it will solved your problem.